# How to form proper query list acording to selected category in Django Solr

Tags: python, django, solr

Can someone explain me if thats an right approach, im trying to form a list of query field in a filter form, depend on what category were selected.

As for now if i select category weapons, in the filter all other fields from other categories, are being shown too like that [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hDEt.png)

Im forming the query in Solr_backend like that

```
 def search_facet(self, query_string, **kwargs):     
        facet_fields = None
        try:
            raw_results = self.conn.search(query_string, facet = 'on' ,** {'facet.field' : ['product_class_exact']})
            facet_fields = raw_results.facets.get('facet_fields', {})
        except (IOError, SolrError) as e:
            if not self.silently_fail:
                raise

            self.log.error("Failed to query Solr using '%s': %s", query_string, e, exc_info=True)
            raw_results = EmptyResults()
        return facet_fields
```

but its returning just a field string, `product_class_exact': [u'T-shirt', 3, u'Classic', 2, u'Common', 2, u'Bow', 1, u'Sword', 1, u'Teleporter', 1]`
Should i form the corresponding dict in this method, or it can be done in different way, as for now i still dont get how to define which field is corresponding to what category !

Comment: @Alexandre Rafalovitch hellom can yo help eme on that =) pls ?

Comment: @Alexandre Rafalovitch i found a  way with using Facet.pivot but i cant find any syntax example how to use it in python

Answer (score 0):

fixed, thx to solr Irc - `self.conn.search(query_string, facet = 'on' ,** {'facet.pivot': 'category_exact,product_class_exact'})`